# How to move a block in magento 1?

Tags: magento-1.9

In magento 2 to move a block I use the following:
`<move element="sidebar.main" destination="category.products.list" after="product_list_toolbar"/>`

But how can I move an element in magento 1?

Answer (score 0):

Generally Magento1 Doesn't have that functionality. so you have to do the following things.

1. Remove the Block code on specific refrenceblock or container from xml file.
2. Add the code on the destination block or container into the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add an example to the [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/344147/31734) of **@Dhiren**.

```xml
<!-- app/code/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/layout/page/local.xml --> 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
  <!-- ... -->
  <cms_page>
    <reference name="content">
      <action method="unsetChild"><name>page_content_heading</name></action>
      <reference name="cms.wrapper">
        <action method="setElementId"><value>cmsPage</value></action>
        <action method="insert"><name>page_content_heading</name></action>
      </reference>
    </reference>
  </cms_page>
</layout>
```

The block named `page_content_heading` gets removed from the content block and is inserted into the `cms.wrapper` block.